# Front end is blank in Magento

Tags: magento, frontend

I am getting blank page in front end, but the back end works fine.  I removed the `#` from  `ini_set('display_errors', 1);`  and added `error_reporting(E_ALL);` . But still I can't find any errors. I also checked error log, nothing there too. Please help

Comment: Which error log did you check? Have you checked Magentos `var/exception.log` and `var/system.log`, too? If you enabled error logging correctly and neither webserver nor Magento log files have anything, then _maybe_ you don't even have any error at all. Maybe your script renders an empty template. Or some `exit;` or `die();` instruction is triggered and just silently cancelling your script. Both could result in a blank page. Did you check for that?

Answer (score 2):

put the following in index.php

```
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true); 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

and see if you get errors detail on frontend and in logs.

Comment: Thanks Chinto for the response. I tried it, still errors are not displaying :(

Comment: Does it take a long time to get to that point, probably an observer failing. Disable all non essential modules and try to find the breakge